# Display User Folder in navigation bar at all times

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Initially, the User Folder is not displayed when opening a new explorer window:

[image: Not displayed]

But as soon as I click the folder in my quick access, it gets displayed:

[image: Displayed]

There is [this hack](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-always-show-user-home-folder-control-panel-and-recycle-bin-items-in-windows-explorers-navigation-pane-in-windows-7/) to display the User Folder in the sidebar at all times for Windows 7. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Windows 10 anymore.

How can I make explorer display this folder at all times?